# Shigeru Miyamoto interview

Tags: translation, word-choice, nuances, particles

I always have difficulty understanding 宮本 茂. His Japanese is like the hardest to understand. I can watch whole anime's with no problem, and read through lots of text in video games and manuals, but Shigeru's speech style is too hard.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VL47n61uihs

Super Mario Run Shigeru Miyamoto Interview feat. Xavier Woods

0:59 seconds:
あのね、やっぱり、技術がほら、ゲームって技術がどんどんどんどん新しい技術が入いて来るし、で、自分自身もどんどん新しい経験していくでしょう、そうすと、すぐにやりたいものがずっと出て来るので

Interpreter in video:

Well and I think you know one of the main reasons that I like to continue to make games is because technology keeps evolving and I keep having you know my own personal life experiences and I keep looking for new ways to combine the two, huh, into new games.

Response from reddit:
Technology in games keeps getting better and better and we also experience more and more. Thus, what you want to do will certainly reveal itself.

My translation:
Well, of course, technology is well, about games new technology keeps coming steadily and steadily, so, my own personal self new experiences of course, thus, soon together coming out because.

Can someone again, please help me make sense of how this sentence was interpreted. I can bet the translations are accurate, I just am looking for a breakdown of the grammar and stuff.

Comment: Listening to anime isn’t quite the same as listening to a human being speaking normally.  Anime is decent listening practice, but the voice actors are carefully recorded in isolated sound booths, their voices are carefully compressed and mixed for maximum intelligibility, and they’re trained to speak very carefully and clearly.  Real speech is different, and if you want to train your brain for it you really need to put yourself out there and talk with real Japanese speakers, preferably in person (to help with sensory integration).

Comment: Thanks snailboat! I hope my questions don't come off as being a troll, or asking stupid things... these are questions which are so confusing I even have trouble finding out how to put them into question format. In either case, I am always grateful and humbled by anyone who assists me with a response. I have asked this 'question' on https://www.reddit.com/r/translator/comments/bf8bta/japaneseenglish_interview/   and https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/%E3%81%BB%E3%82%89.3568407/    , from which I have also received good responses. Also wanted to add that I find 宮本茂 to be hard to understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Allow me to provide a more literal, humanized translation... The translations you received appear to be normalized so that they resemble a more standard, formal way of speaking.

I haven't watched the video so I'm missing some context, but

> あのね、やっぱり、技術がほら、

So like, really, technology is like, hey!

> ゲームって技術がどんどんどんどん新しい技術が入いて来るし、

The technology in games, again and again and again and again, new technology is put into games...

> で、自分自身も

And so I myself (also)...

> どんどん新しい経験していくでしょう

Again and again, continuously move forward, gaining new experiences...

> そうすと「そうすると」、すぐにやりたいものがずっと出て来るので

And so, things you want to do will keep appearing...

Comment: @Will To be fair, what bugs me is the drive by rather than the vote itself... I'd like to know what I may have done wrong!

Comment: @Will Please read our [Code of Conduct](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/conduct).  Insulting your fellow users like that for any reason is not allowed on this site.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few minor errors in the transcription which I've corrected below:

> あのね、やっぱり、技術がほら、
>   ゲームって技術がどんどんどんどん新しい技術が**入って**くるし、
>   で、自分自身もどんどん新しい経験していくでしょう。
>   そう**する**と、**次に**やりたいものがずっと出てくるので

The following is a part-by-part translation/paraphrasing:

> ゲームって技術がどんどんどんどん新しい技術が入ってくるし

New techniques, styles, and technology are constantly being introduced in games

Note: Given the topic of making video games, I believe 技術 here encompasses both the technology (e.g. more advanced game engines, better hardware) and the creative skills/techniques (e.g. art direction, sound, animation, programming) used to create a video game.

> で、自分自身もどんどん新しい経験していくでしょう。

So I, myself continue to experience new things as well

> そうすると、次にやりたいものがずっと出てくるので

And so there's always something I want to try making next

To summarize and add my interpretation: Shigeru Miyamoto has been creating games for many decades now. What spurs him on to keep creating games to this day are his love of games and the constant influx of new techniques/technology that allows him to continue learning and have new experiences. Given these factors, after he's done working on one game, there's no shortage of new game ideas he wants to try working on next.